# ssh redirect output of Unix pwd command to a file il the local server

Tags: ssh

#### Script abcd.sh:

```
####
ssh $user_name@$ftp_site pwd > /export/home/appwxsms/remotepathfile.lst;
pathofremote =`sed -n '1p' $HOME/remotepathfile.lst`
export  pathofremote
#####
```

#### Running abcd.sh:

```
-bash:./abcd.sh
 pathofremote: command not found

remotepathfile.lst > output.txt
-bash: /export/home/appwxsms/remotepathfile1.lst: Permission denied
```

While running the abcd.sh script I am not able to sed the output of the file  generated in local path remotepathfile.lst to the variable `pathofremote`

Also I am not able to save the output of the file to another file in the localserver.

Comment: At a minimum, remove the space between `pathofremote` and `=`

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the syntactical error in your variable assignment, the file will be populated as you wish it to be.

```
foo =bar     # This will attempt to run the command 'foo' with the parameter '=bar'
foo=bar      # This will set the variable 'foo' equal to 'bar'
foo="$(bar)" # This will set the variable 'foo' to the output of the execution of 'bar'
```